# My CSS and images aren't loading once the HTML file is hosted on a server. Why?

Tags: html, css

I am hosting the website on a home server so we aren't going through a third party. Even though I have the CSS linked, the file in the same area as the HTML, and the images all set up just one file away, nothing is showing up aside form basic HTML.

Please let me know if you've run into this problem of the HTML file working UNTIL it's hosted on our server and how you've fixed it. Thank you!

When I load just the HTML file in my browser (chrome) everything shows up beautifully, but once I try to host it, nothing looks the same.

Here is some of the code I used to link the CSS file and the images just to make sure there's nothing wrong there:

```
<head>
  <title>Alexandra ReganHolzheimer</title>
  <link href="pages_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
media="screen">
</head>
```

And for the images:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="img/me3.jpg" alt="me" class="logo">
</div>
```

UPDATE:  I think I figured it out. The issue turned out to be that my server didn't like underscores and a lot was case sensitive. Your suggestions were super helpful and put me on the right path. 
thank you!

Comment: What does your file structure look like? Also, what server are you using?

Comment: Most likely, all you need is to prefix your current values with `/` (`href="pages_style.css"` becomes `href="/pages_style.css"`).

Comment: Look in your browser's console at the errors generated by the broken links. They'll tell you what they tried to load. If you can't figure out how to modify your url's so they load properly, update your question with one of those errors.

Answer (score 0):

Once u load your URL on browser. Then see the page source. In pagesource please check your css is loading correct or not. If error means please correct it and then load again.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue when I tried hosting one of my learning projects onto a server.
I fixed it by making all the references relative.

For example: 
If your file structure is like:

`your_project /
    pages_style.css
    index.html
    img/`

Just change your paths, from: `img/me3.jpg` to `./img/me3.jpg` in your `index.html`.

I hope it helps. :)